# How to set user location to i18n?

Tags: vue.js, locale, vue-i18n

I would like to set the application language by getting the language used by the user's browser and I know that I can do this via `navigator.language` and I can also apply it to `main` using something like: `locale = navigator.language || navigator.userLanguage`.

However, I find it interesting that the user has the option to change the language if they prefer, so I did something like this on a Settings page:

```html
<select v-model="$i18n.locale">
  <option
    v-for="locale in $i18n.availableLocales"
    :key="`locale-${locale}`"
    :value="locale"
  >
    {{ locale }}
  </option>
</select>
```

However, to apply the change to a `main.js` file I will need to fix the Locales, as I had made a strange solution and now I need to fix it before continuing:

```js
import { createI18n } from "vue-i18n/index";
import en from "./en.json";
import ja from "./ja.json";
import pt from "./pt-br.json";

const messages = {
  "English": en,
  "Português": pt,
  "日本語": ja,
};

// Create i18n instance with options
export const i18n = createI18n({
  locale: "English",
  fallbackLocale: ["Português", "日本語"],
  messages,
});
```

Although this is working, it seems to me to be very incorrect. This strange solution allowed the user to see **English** instead of **en**, **Português** instead of **pt**, etc... but now I'll need to fix this.

So how could I display the values of locations instead of their keys without this workaround I created?

And later on, is the way in which I intend to define the language really the best?

Comment: Try `window.navigator.language`, which will return the users language (like `en-GB`), or `undefined`. Then you can check if that language exists, if so, apply it, and if not apply the default language.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get a list of your apps supported languages

```js
const availibleLocales = this.$i18n.availableLocales;
```

Then, get the users browser's language

```js
const usersLanguage = window.navigator.language
```

Then, if the users language is supported apply it. Otherwise apply the default language

```js
if (availibleLocales.includes(usersLanguage)) {
  this.$i18n.locale = language;
} else {
  this.$i18n.locale = 'en';
}
```

All of this would be done in your upper-most component (usually `App.ts`), and kicked off within the `mounted()` method.

Comment: Amazing solution, @Alicia. I really appreciate. But is it possible to set a "beautiful" value for 'en' and 'pt' like 'English' and 'Portuguese'.So the user can pick the one he wants.

Comment: Usually it's best practice to use the language's ISO code for selecting languages, but what you can do is have an array of JSON objects for each language, and include a text string with that, which is then displayed in the UI. Here's and example, of how I've done it in the past: https://github.com/Lissy93/dashy/blob/master/src/utils/languages.js